# Angular ng-paste input box - X clear icon

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement the following requirement with ng-paste. Browser is IE. Angular 1.6

I have an input box similar to the following;

```
<input type="text" maxlength=12 ng-paste="handlePaste($event, 12, 'memberID')"/>
```

If membership ID number is always a 12 digit number. The user often copy and pastes the ID number from another document. Sometimes by mistake they might copy a leading blank space and the input box crops the 12 character. It is not immediately obvious to the user that they are missing one character.

I have implemented a handlepaste function similar to the following which allows me to trim the text and i can paste the text into the input box. The problem is when I click the X button in the input box, i can not past into the input again until i change focus to another item on the page and then return to the input box. Has anyone encountered and solved this problem?

```
$scope.handlePaste = function(e, maxLength,propName){
    e.preventdefault();
    $scope.applicationID2 = "";
      var pastedText;
      if(typeof e.originalEvent.clipboardData !== "undefined"){
         pastedText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      } else if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
         pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
      } else {
          pastedText = angular.element(e.currentTarget).val();
      }
      pastedText = pastedText.trim();
    //  alert(pastedText);
      $scope.applicationID2 = pastedText;
```

Comment: "The problem is when I click the X button in the input box" Where is this X button in your code?

Comment: IE displays the X with the html i have added as above, there is no code that i need to add.